# regular expression for extracting multiple dates

Tags: php, regex

I have a text which contain two dates, i want to extract both dates from the text, what would be regular expression for this text.

```
he was out of city in period of 10/15/16 Sat 7am - 10/16/16 Sun 3am ₨350.00/hr - you have to remain onlines, which will enable you to meet him.
```

I have multiple strings with different text but each string has two dates. How I can get these dates in php. just want to get dates 10/15/16 and 10/16/16

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: what is this: `₨350.00/hr`? should it be matched?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])\/([0][1-9]]|[12]\d|3[01])\/\d{2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s(\d|1[012])[ap]m
```

See this in [Action at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BshesL/4)

if you only want to match valid dates:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])\/([0][1-9]]|[12]\d|3[01])\/\d{2}
```

See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/BshesL/5)

Answer (score 0):

If you use this pattern it will capture the format x(x)/x(x)/xx(xx).
Meaning one or two digit day and month and two or four digit year.

```
$string = "he was out of city in period of 10/15/2016 Sat 7am - 10/16/16 Sun 3am ₨350.00/hr - you have to remain onlines, which will enable you to meet him.";
preg_match_all("/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})/", $string, $dates);


var_dump($dates[1]);
```